# OpenCV webcam capture

Tags: python, opencv

I'm afraid I have run into something a bit beyond the scope of my novice abilities. A quick summary of the problem: I am attempting to capture a live video stream during an experiment (using OpenSesame) from a webcam using the OpenCV python module. I can get it to work, but my issue is that the code pops open a new window to show the live stream that it is recording. How would I alter this code to NOT show the live window but still be able to press 'q' to shut off the live stream?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

subject = str(self.get('subject_nr'))
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
w=int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH ))
h=int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT ))

#Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('path\to\output'+ subject + '.avi', -1, 20.0, (w,h))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:

        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

#Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you try commenting `cv2.imshow('frame',frame)` and try
`if( (cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q') ) break;`

Comment: Ah, thanks for your reply! We are getting close! The code runs and records, but I still can't use a keystroke to release the job.

Comment: Can you trying keystroke with console active?

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing with the console active. It just freezes and I have to exit out to stop the script.

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.waitKey()` captures keystrokes from the highgui window. You cannot use `waitKey` to capture keystrokes if you never display the window. You will need something that can capture keystrokes from the terminal.

For linux, you can achieve this using `termios` and `fcntl` modules. Here is an example from Python's documentation.
https://docs.python.org/2/faq/library.html#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! So I did some internet searching and was able to get the script working with `msvcrt.kbhit()` (I'm on Windows), but now the issue is that it is not saving the webcam stream to the specified location. I feel like I am so close, or am just blind to a blaring error here. All I did was insert `if msvcrt.kbhit():
                if (msvcrt.getch() == "q"):
                    break` below `out.write(frame)`

Comment: @DrPineapple I'm not sure but maybe you need the waitKey for videowriter too. Try moving this statement below the waitKey statement. Once again, this is just a guess.